# Is there a way to get the local time and time of an oracle database server using java's LocalDateTime class?

Tags: java, timezone, jpql, java-time, localdatetime

To get the current time of my machine's location, and use its value to set the parameter for a jpql query, this code works fine:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
query.setParameter("myTime", Timestamp.valueOf(now)); //using the current machine time to set parameter for a jpql query
```

In a different test case, I want to use the value of the current time of the system where the oracle database resides, rather than that of my local machine. Is there a way to get this using the same `LocalDateTime` class? If it's not possible with this class, what's the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, this depends on what JPA provider you're using. Since you've mentioned JPQL you're probably not using criteria queries so if your provider is Hibernate you might have luck using the built-in HQL function `current_timestamp()`. However, the DB's time should be the same as your application's (the servers should use a timing service to keep time consistent) and thus this shouldn't matter. (Different time zones would _not_ actually mean different times, just different representations).

Comment: @Thomas, are you able to demonstrate the use of `current_timestamp()` in relation to my code?

Comment: Since you didn't post much code that's hard to do. However, assuming your query looks like `... where xxx = :myTime` you should be able to use `... where xxx = current_timestamp()` instead (again: this refers to Hibernate, I'm not sure about other JPA providers)

Comment: @Thomas, the query in the entity class looks like this: `@NamedQuery(name = "findByTime", query = "select u from TestEntity u where u.date < :myTime")`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the value of the current time of the system where the
> oracle database resides, rather than that of my local machine. Is
> there a way to get this using the same LocalDateTime class?

### [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)

Returns a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone, retaining the instant.

Let's say the time-zone of the system where your Oracle DB runs is `America/New_York`. You can find the `LocalDateTime` at that time-zone using this method.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Zone ID of the system where Oracle DB runs
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        System.out.println(getLocalDateTimeNowAtZoneId(zoneId));
    }

    static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeNowAtZoneId(ZoneId zoneId) {
        return ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameInstant(zoneId).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-17T18:37:04.456820
```